# How do I return the type of a variable in minizinc?

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I'd like to do something like this:

```
enum COLORS = {"green", "red", "blue"};
output [show(type(COLORS)];
```

And I would expect this to output `enum`. I can't seem to find out from the docs how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MiniZinc currently does not include any [reflection operations](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.5.5/en/lib-stdlib.html#reflection-operations) that will allow you to get the name of the type.

Your example might actually not be a great one, because the `enum` keyword semantically creates a new type, in this case `COLORS`. So my intuition for what a `type` function would return would be `COLORS`, not `enum`.

If you feel this could be a useful feature (and you maybe have a more extensive example where this is used), then you can submit an issue to the MiniZinc issue tracker: https://github.com/MiniZinc/libminizinc/issues